# how to create a pie chart in asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, web-controls

I want to do a pie chart in mvc 2, any suggestion ?.

Thankx

Comment: From scratch or via a 3rd party library? Would suggest the latter unless you really, really like doing owner-drawn graphics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the link http://code-inside.de/blog-in/2008/11/27/howto-use-the-new-aspnet-chart-controls-with-aspnet-mvc/

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 2):

You could use Microsoft's free (but powerful) [.NET charting controls](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart).

Comment: I'm vaguely offended (but only slightly) by the implication that "free" would otherwise indicate that something would _not_ be powerful :)

Answer (score 0):

There is also other optios like fusion charts.

See a sample here

[http://liberofusioncharts.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single%20Series%20Chart%2c%20adding%20data%20by%20DataSource%20-%20MVC&referringTitle=Home](http://liberofusioncharts.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single%20Series%20Chart,%20adding%20data%20by%20DataSource%20-%20MVC&referringTitle=Home)

Answer (score 0):

Check ShieldUI Charts for ASP.NET MVC:

http://demos.shieldui.com/mvc/area-chart/axis-marker

It is a very powerful library, with a lot of customization options and many other user interface controls one might need.